# Set CPU frequency in Windows 10 no longer works

Tags: windows, windows-10, power-management, cpu-speed

I used to set max CPU frequency by enabling this option:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Power\PowerSettings\54533251-82be-4824-96c1-47b60b740d00\75b0ae3f-bce0-45a7-8c89-c9611c25e100
```

(set `Attributes` to 2)

Which adds **Maximum processor frequency** setting to power options. Since boosting too hard is not very efficient I like to reduce boost frequency, but I like to still have some boost over base frequency. For example on Xeon E-2388G the base requency is 3.2GHz and I set it to 3400 for long power hungry tasks like encoding and archiving.

That worked before and at some point it stopped working. I set the frequency but the CPU goes over the set freqency. I found the setting `75b0ae3f-bce0-45a7-8c89-c9611c25e101` and I also set it, but it doesn't work anymore:

[image: Setup]

That happened on two PCs and a laptop at about the same time (updates?).

**Update:**
On the Xeon E2388G machine limiting below base frequency (3200) works. If I try to limit to 3400 for example it just boosts to 4600 and then when it gets back to 95W limit settles to 3700-3800 as it always does...

On i9-13900k it's more complicated. If I do this:

```
powercfg /setACvalueindex scheme_current SUB_PROCESSOR PROCFREQMAX 2500
powercfg /setACvalueindex scheme_current SUB_PROCESSOR PROCFREQMAX1 3200
powercfg /setDCvalueindex scheme_current SUB_PROCESSOR PROCFREQMAX 2500
powercfg /setDCvalueindex scheme_current SUB_PROCESSOR PROCFREQMAX1 3200

powercfg /setactive scheme_current
```

I get 100 less than PROCFREQMAX1 on all cores(unless I set more than 4300 - then E-cores stay capped at 4300).

If I set **PROCFREQMAX only** - **no effect**.

if I set **PROCFREQMAX1 only**, regardless of the value all cores get capped to E-cores max boost - 4300.

Setting **Processor performance boost mode**  makes no difference. (be337238-0d82-4146-a960-4f3749d470c7)

It's a mess.

Comment: See if the last entry in [this post](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/power-plan-cpu-frequency-settings-affect-only-e/ebe030fe-7c02-406f-bd15-3221108552f0) helps.

Comment: Why do you believe that boosting is not efficient? Spending a shorter time at a higher frequency so that you can fall back down to a low idle frequency or even being able to shut down the core *can* result in efficiency gains. https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/race-to-sleep

Comment: @Mokubai Because I measured it. After some frequency you get diminishing returns. For bigger increase of power you get not much increase in frequency. For example let's say that 1 thread (for simplicity) at 1 GHz rises the cpu power from 10 to 15W (not exact numbers). at 2 GHz 20W, at 3 - 25 and at some point power grows faster - at 4 you may get 33W and at  5 you may get 40W and 5.8 - 50W. Again - hypothetical numbers. But I measured whatt hours to do a task at different fequencies and at highest boost frequencies it's more than at lower.

Comment: @harrymc I'll check it. thanks

Comment: Holding a CPU at a higher frequency will indeed use more power, that is a given in electronics, with higher frequencies using increasingly more power. The thing is though that it is that act of holding that frequency that wastes power. Holding the CPU at a lower frequency might well save some power if you *immediately* turn off that frequency hold when done, but if you forget or leave it for half an hour then you could easily waste more power than just letting the processor overclock itself and then run to idle and let the core put itself to sleep after, which may not happen with your method.

Comment: @Mokubai The current issue is about windows frequency limit not working, not about efficiency. But you are wrong. Race-to-sleep minimizes power during idle periods (when there is not much to do). It's turned on in bios and it only boosts to max (regardless of the limits) when there is no much to do. My 13900k idles at 10W limited to 3.9GHz and 15-20W with no limits (5.5-5.8GHz standard boost). That's with few browser tabs open. with nothing open - makes no difference. I only turn off limits because working with the pc I prefer smooth operation over power efficiency.